# input type="submit" doesn't trigger HttpPost in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, submit

I'm starting to get confused. I just started building a site and stumbled upon a problem with my controller. It doesn't post at all, with or without parameters. I want to add that I just moved the ActionResult method from another controller and the View as well. It's probably something obvious but getting tired and figured I'd ask for clarification!

Viewpath/name: Views/Table/Registrations

```
@foreach (var registration in ViewBag.AllRegistrations)
    {
      using (Html.BeginForm("Registrations", "Table", new { regid = registration.RegistrationId }))
      {
         <tr class="odd gradeX">
          <td>
            <input type="submit" name="command" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" />&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="command" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" />
          </td>
         </tr>

      }
    }
```

Controllername: TableController

```
public ActionResult Registrations()
{
    ViewBag.AllRegistrations = registration.SelectAll();
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registrations(int regid, string command)
{
    //doesn't post
    return View();
}
```

Routeconfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Table", action = "Registrations", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: can u do a Ctrl M + Ctrl G on the View() ? (the one with HttpPost).  that would indicate what view you are going to display.

Comment: Not related, but your route has `{id}` but in your `BeginForm()` and in the POST method you have `regid` You should use `new { id = registration.RegistrationId }` and `Registrations(int id, string command)` if your wanting to match your route (or change `{id}` to `{regid}` and make it `regid = UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: Also it this all inside a `<table>` element - in which case you have invalid html (a `<form>` element is not a valid child of a `<table>`

Comment: That was my problem Stephen Muecke! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int regid, string command)
{

```
//Insert some logic
```

}

Instead of setting the default routes you could just set the action/method name to be the same as your button "value"

This would probably make your code more readable because you could have actions/methods called create, edit, delete for instance. I hope that helps

Also where is your post logic/code? At the moment your post action is just returning a view. What are you trying to do in that method?